# 4 items failed with the test of https://2018-dot-qual-e.appspot.com in cobalt RC_11 11.99532

Tags: cobalt

We tested the https://2018-dot-qual-e.appspot.com with `cobalt rc_11 11.99532 qa version` on arm-linux platform, but the following `4` items would fail, could anyone help to have a look?

```
1. Conformance -> Functionality & MSE/EME  
1.1 Item 'CSP script-src url/CSP Level 2' would fail;
1.2 Item 'script-src nonce' would fail;

2. WebP -> Animated WebP
2.1 GIF has no animation, but it has animation on windows chrome;

3. ETC -> Cookies
3.1 The cookies can not be cleared, but it can be cleared on windows chrome;
```

Comment: What do you want us to do about it?

Comment: Hi bitchainer, up-front I can say that GIF format support is not supported by Cobalt, but it is not a requirement either, it is okay and expected that it does not work.

As for the other two issues, we can look into them and get back to you.

Comment: By the way, concerning the cookies page, a problem with it was fixed recently, do you still encounter errors with it?

Comment: Ahhh, and I'm able to reproduce #1 when I pass in "--csp_mode=disable", and since those tests explicitly test that CSP is working, they certainly will fail in this case.  For those tests, you can try leaving out "--csp_mode=disable", or pass in "--disable_navigation_whitelist" instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. I will separate out those two tests from Conformance as it is expected not to work with --csp_mode=disable.
2. GIF is just used to show how it looks like. It is not a requirement and not supported by Cobalt.
3. I will take a look at this issue.